# PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small %ROWTYPE

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I don't know if I am missing something but what I am doing is:

I have a function that returns a ROWTYPE

```
  FUNCTION myFunc(pChar CHAR) RETURN myTable%ROWTYPE AS
    myTable_rec myTable%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    INTO myTable_rec.col1 
      , myTable_rec.col2
      , myTable_rec.col3
    FROM myTable
    WHERE col4 = pChar;

    RETURN(myTable_rec);
  END B001_03;
```

then in my procedure (which calls the function above), I declared:

```
myTable_rec myTable%ROWTYPE;
```

but when I call in the procedure:

```
...
myTable_rec := myFunc(someChar);
...
```

I get

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

Aren't the fields supposed to be FROM the same table and OF THE SAME datatype (as of my little understanding)?

EDIT:
I tried to SELECT * and every works. I am definitely missing something here. I just don't know that it is.

Comment: why don't you use Varchar2 instead of Char?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bet the problem originates from using Char which is a fixed length string. Not sure where, but somewhere in your code you try to put a Char or varchar2 string of length N into a char of lengh M where M > N.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error while accessing Oracle SP through my .Net code.
If someone is facing this error then for him/her **specifying the size of the input / output parameter** would help solving the issue.

Sample code goes like this :

OracleParameter oparamProjectId = mycom.Parameters.Add("p_open_flag", OracleDbType.**Varchar2**);
                oparamProjectId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                **oparamProjectId.Size = 100**;

Comment: Perfect! After a long time trying to find the error finally I know why. Thank you very much!